# How do you disable print log of an external library's function?

Tags: python

### Problem

I'm importing `nltk` and downloading data for it:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
```

The problem is, every time I run the program, `nltk.download` displays the log in the console:

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package averaged_perceptron_tagger to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\f\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package averaged_perceptron_tagger is already up-to-
[nltk_data]       date!
```

### Question

Is there a way to prevent it? It's a console program and I'd like it to show only the stuff I want it to.

Comment: How about suppressing the message when using `evaluate`? `import evaluate` and then `bleu = evaluate.load('sacrebleu')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `nltk.download()` call from your code after downloading the required packages once. By keeping the line you are essentially downloading it each time your run the program and hence the log message.

Comment: I think it only attempts to re-download it. But yeah, I guess it makes sense to not leave it in the program.

Comment: But what if I move the program to another computer? Should I just run `nltk.download()` as a console command (so it's not showing log in the main console window)? The following doesn't seem to work from within the program `os.system("python")` `os.system("nltk.download(...))` it opens another console window and runs `python` command, but not the other command

Comment: Yup, it checks the local file before downloading and if it is already in the latest version it skips downloading it. Another fun fact about nltk packages is once you load them in the memory it caches them internally so you dont have to worry about reading from the disk for each run, if you load it once, it will reuse it from cache for all runs thereafter.

Comment: Yes, if you were to say run your command in some other system such as an EC2 instance, you would need to run all these commands again so it can be downloaded locally, the other alternative is to alter the nltk search path to some custom location and package your code with the libraries you need, so it can directly fetch them, off the top of my head another hack would be to create a file that notes if the download command has been run on the system in the past, (you can update this based on your needs) and download only if it has not been executed before.

Answer (score 6):

you can also pass quiet=True while downloading

```
import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet', quiet=True)
```