# nltk - prevent logs from imported library

Tags: python, nltk, chatterbot

I'm using the python chatterbot library and it's printing the following when i'm creating a new chatbot `chatbot = ChatBot('New')`

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to
[nltk_data]     /home/linux/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!
[nltk_data] Downloading package averaged_perceptron_tagger to
[nltk_data]     /home/linux/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package averaged_perceptron_tagger is already up-to-
[nltk_data]       date!
```

Comment: Isn't it because `chatterbot` use `NLTK` library for tokenizing, pos, and etc. ?

Comment: yes, is there any way to stop these logs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50804099/how-do-you-disable-print-log-of-an-external-librarys-function may help you

Comment: But where shall I put `nltk.download('wordnet', quiet=True)`? I didn't created `chatterbot`

Comment: I am having the same difficulty where I do not understand where to use quiet=True, since I am never downloading a specific package, just importing. Did you ever find a solution?